# How to find element with specifc attribute value and element value

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

Please help with a xpath expression as explained below

```
   <A>
     <B x="P" Z="flag">2</B>
     <B x="Q" Z="nonflag"></B>
     <B x="R" Z="flag">3</B>
  </A>
```

How do i find out element `A/B`with Attribute `Z` as `flag` and element value as `2`.. in this example the first `<B x="P" Z="flag">2</B>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are preceded by `@` in XPath. You can chain the predicates one after another:

```
A/B[@Z="flag"][text()="2"]
```

or use `and`:

```
A/B[@Z="flag" and text()="2"]
```

You can also say `.="2"` instead of `text()="2"`, but it has a slightly different meaning if the element has subelements.

(Tested in [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh)).